# How iterate through json object in c#

Tags: c#, json

im using the next code:

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reader.ReadToEnd());

foreach (var item in jsonObj)

{

 Console.WriteLine("");

}
```

Where `reader.ReadToEnd()` has a json string.

But i have an error on foreach,

> Error 13  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable' because
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a public definition
>   for
>   'GetEnumerator'   C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\app\appRecept\Paises.cs 47  29  appPreregistro

Comment: How does your json structure look like? Does it look like an array or a list in watch window?

Comment: my json looks like this:

{
  "success" : "true",
  "states" : [ {
   "id" : "1000",
   "name" : "AGUASCALIENTES",
   
  }, {
   "id" : "1001",
   "name" : "BAJA CALIFORNIA",
   
  }, {
   "id" : "1002",
   "name" : "BAJA CALIFORNIA SUR",
   
  }, {
                        "id" : "1004",
   "name" : "ZACATECAS",
   
  } ]
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're deserializing an array of objects from JSON, something that looks like this:

```
[
  {blah},
  {blah},
  {blah}
]
```

then deserialize to a List type:

```
var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: my json looks like this:
`{ "success" : "true", "states" : [ { "id" : "1000", "name" : "AGUASCALIENTES", }, { "id" : "1001", "name" : "BAJA CALIFORNIA", }, { "id" : "1002", "name" : "BAJA CALIFORNIA SUR", }, { "id" : "1004", "name" : "ZACATECAS", } ] }`

The way you deserialize the string object throug an exception :
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type list, because the type requires a JSON  array

Comment: If you want to loop through the states, then change your loop to: foreach (var item in jsonObj.states)